# why do my onClick functions take two clicks

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I've noticed from a few different projects of mine that whenever I click something I add an onClick function to, it always takes two clicks to get them going when a page is freshly loaded.  The general structure I use for them is:

```
function PageChange(){

    var welc_p = document.getElementById("welcome");/**gathers page DIVs**/
    var page01 = document.getElementById("page01");
    var page02 = document.getElementById("page02");

    var start = document.getElementById("start_btn");/**gathers buttons**/
    var p1_back = document.getElementById("p1_back");
    var p1_next = document.getElementById("p1_back");

    var p2_back = document.getElementById("p2_back");
    var p2_next = document.getElementById("p2_back");

    start.onclick=function(){
        page01.style.display="block";
        welc_p.style.display="none";
        window.location="#page01";
        };

    }/**function**/
```

then the way I call it in the html is

```
<div class="some_class" id="start_btn" onClick="PageChange()">!!!LETS GET STARTED!!!</div>
```

Here's a fiddle of it as well.
https://jsfiddle.net/Optiq/42e3juta/

this is generally how I structure it each time I want to create this functionality.  I've seen tons of other posts on here about their items taking 2 clicks to activate but none of them were doing anything near what I was trying to accomplish and it seemed their problem was within their coding. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because you are attatching a [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) to your button *on click* of your button.
This means that one click of the button activates the event handler, not the code within `start.onclick=function() {`
Then, the second click works becasue the event handler has been activated, and now the code will run.

Try moving your code out of the function, then it will work with just one click

Comment: ok I get what you mean with 2 functions being called, but I'm a little lost on moving my code outside of the function...

do you mean making it start.onclick=*coding*? or are you talking about something down in the html?

Comment: Nope, just remove the line `function PageChange(){` and also the matching `}` later on @DaMightyOptiq

Comment: but if I take that out how will the onclick on the button know which function I'm telling it to do?

Comment: The line `start.onclick=function(){` should take care of that, as you have already defined the variable `start`

Comment: ok I just added it to the question, sorry for the delay, all of a sudden when I clicked save the fiddle would just disappear and not give a share link.  never did that before.

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://jsfiddle.net/jofish999/d3nL727w/ @DaMightyOptiq

Comment: YES!!!.... but now I'm even more lost, I took that part out of my code and now it doesn't work at all..... yet it works in the fiddle.  I didn't see any difference in the html.

Comment: Ok, can you try putting `window.onload=function() {` where the `function PageChange()` was? And remember to re-add the closing bracket `}`

Comment: So out of the function block your code was running before the page was ready. Adding `window.onload` makes the code run only after the page has loaded, so that you are accessing (with getElementById) an element that actually exists @DaMightyOptiq

Comment: And that's great! Any chance you could mark it as the correct answer? @DaMightyOptiq

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same 2 clicks required on intitial interaction and after many searches couldn't find the best solution for my specific nav menu. I tried this solution above but couldn't get it to work.

Stumbled upon this code from a youtube example and it solved my issue. I wanted to nest submenu's for multiple levels and modified it from its original implementation to work best for my responsive mobile menu.

```js
var a;
function toggleFirstLevelMobileSubMenu(){
    if(a==1){
        document.getElementById("mobile-sub-menu-depth-1").style.display="none";
        return a=0;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("mobile-sub-menu-depth-1").style.display="flex";
        return a=1;
    }
}

var b;
function toggleSecondLevelMobileSubMenu(){
    if(b==1){
        document.getElementById("mobile-sub-menu-depth-2").style.display="none";
        return b=0;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("mobile-sub-menu-depth-2").style.display="flex";
        return b=1;
    }
}
```

Of course, in the CSS I had `display: none` set for both ID's.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue, and found an easy solution based on the above answer.
Since your function needs two clicks to work, I just called the function above the function and it works fine. This way the function already gets called one time on load, then it gets called the second time when you click it.

```
yourFunction();

function yourFunction(){
  -- content -- 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

First, the problem:- On first click instead of running js your browser runs the button aka the event.
Solution:- in order to resolve this we need to make sure our function is already before the event is run (this is one of the ways to solve the problem). To achive this we need to load the function aka call the function in some way.
So, i just simply called the function after function is completed.
Code answer-

Just add at the end of your code

```
PageChange();
```